# Display hour with 15 min interval in django template

Tags: django, templates

I need to print dropdown menu with time selection in django template like:

```
12:00 AM
12:15 AM
12:30 AM
(...)
```

All hours should be visible.
Is there any simple way to do it in Django template without coding it inside the view or manual typing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible only with the templating language unless you write a custom tag for this.
But this can be easily achieved with 3 lines of python in your view:

```
times = []
for i in range(0, 24*4):
  times.append((datetime.combine(date.today(), time()) + datetime.timedelta(minutes=15) * i).time().strftime("%I:%M %p"))
```

in your template:

```
{% for time in times %}
    <option>{{ time }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```